# How to track the query speed in sqlite3?

Tags: database, sqlite, caching, ram

My remote sever has a 200Gb RAM, I set the `cache_size` to 5000000, `page_size` to 4096, which means it should be able to load 20 GB data, but when I was running query like `select count(table1.item1) from table1, table2 on table1.id = table2.id where table2.item1=1234;`on a 2.5 TB database , it showed that the memory usage was only around 1 Gb, the CPU usage is like 0 to 7% and the query could never be ended, I waited like 24 hours.. so can I somehow track how many data are already loaded there, and what is the speed when loading the data, or something like that?

table structure:

```
table1:
   id integer primary key,
   item1 integer

table2:
   id integer,
   item1 integer

-- the DB without index was 0.8 TB after the three indices is now 2.5 TB
indices on: table1.item1, table2.id, table2.item1
```

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: @tonypdmtr Hey, I completed that information at the description.

Comment: Have you tried without indices (having a smaller database file may help somewhat).  Anyway, are both tables in the same database or do you `ATTACH` another database to access the other table?  This because there was a similar case where it was too slow with `ATTACH` but moving both tables to the same database made a huge speed difference.  Also, setting a too big cache may have 'diminishing returns'.

Comment: @tonypdmtr hey, sorry that I haven't replied in time since my laptop was broken. Indeed, the tables are in the same database but they were attached from another databse, because of the limited `page_size` of the first datebase,I build the second one by attaching the tables from the first database by `ATTACH 'database2file' AS db2; INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM db2.t2`, was it the reson why it acted so slow? Btw, I did not undertand, my RAM is 200GB,  `page_size = 4096` but if `cache_size` is set over 500000, then the RAM consumption went exceed. Does the `cache_size` actually refers to RAM?